# Using Valgrind with Qt from command line to debug memory error

Tags: c++, qt, heap-memory, valgrind

I'm having a memory error in my Qt-based application, I'm trying to use the Valgrind tool to detect the error but unfortunately when using Valgrind with my executable it runs and finishes without opening the GUI.

My command used is:
valgrind --track-origin=yes executable_path

The output is:

```
==4982== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4982== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4982== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4982== Command: executable_path
==4982== 
==4982== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4982==     in use at exit: 2,661,594 bytes in 33,665 blocks
==4982==   total heap usage: 36,967 allocs, 3,302 frees, 3,228,496 bytes allocated
==4982== 
==4982== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4982==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4982==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4982==      possibly lost: 1,962,915 bytes in 27,027 blocks
==4982==    still reachable: 698,679 bytes in 6,638 blocks
==4982==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4982== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4982== 
==4982== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4982== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 10 from 6)
```

My expectation is that this command will open the GUI and I'll do the steps for reproducing the issue then when I close the tool the report is written in the terminal, so what is wrong with the command that causes Valgrind to finish before even opening the tool.

Comment: Have you tried running valgrind from within Qt Creator?

Comment: You do not mention what the produced output is. Or does neither valgrind nor your executable produce any output at all?

Comment: Hi @LudwigSchulze, Sorry for that, I've added the output.

Comment: Hi @JarMan, Unfortunately, I'm working in an environment with an old Qt creator that doesn't support Valgrind integration.

Comment: You are probably invoking not the correct binary. It is called executable_path in your output example. Give valgrind the complete absolute path and make sure that your latest binary is really at that location. Also double-check that the same invocation without valgrind really opens the GUI as you expect.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze, I'm calling it here so in order not to expose the working environment.
What do you mean by the latest binary? This executable if invoked without Valgrind it opens the GUI.

Comment: If you are sure that your are invoking the exact same command, once with valgrind and once without, then the only thing I can think of to explain such a behaviour difference are timeouts: valgrind slows down execution significantly. Maybe some part of your program runs into a timeout and decides to exit. BTW, my valgrind version does not understand --track-origin=yes, it is valgrind-3.17.0. Maybe also try without this option. Also make sure that you are executing the real compiled program, not some wrapper script with valgrind.

Comment: @LudwigSchulze I tried without and unfortunately it's the same, I'll investigate the timeout idea you specified, thank you for helping.

Comment: @AmrEssam I suggest putting a `printf("Hello!\n");` at the top of your program's `main()` just to see if it gets printed when you run under valgrind (and also to see if it gets printed when you run the same executable without valgrind)

Comment: Use vgdb to see exactly what is happening. Run Valgrind with --vgdb-error=0, attacj gdb as per the instructions and then continue to debug as usual with gdb.